# Speeding up table view cell loading with UINib

Tags: android, ios, iphone, xmpp, chat

I am developing iPhone chat application.

After run an app, when I clicked any chat room, there is exist delay for 1~2sec while opening the chat room.

This delay will occur only first time after run.

After back to chat room list, when I clicked any chat room again, there is no exist delay.

When I see the whatsapp, there is no any delay and opened the chat room immediately as soon as clicked chat room.

Now, on viewWillAppear, Current chat room messages has been fetched from DB and I called reloadData of UITableView.

Anyone know why there are exist delay?

Or Anyone know perfect architecture to open chat room without any delay?

Please advice me, Thank you.

ChatRoomsViewController class

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
...
self.chat_board = [[ChatBoardViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ChatBoardViewController" bundle:nil];

UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ChatBoardRightCell" bundle:nil];
[_chat_board.board_table registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ChatBoardRightCell"];

nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ChatBoardLeftCell" bundle:nil];
[_chat_board.board_table registerNib:nib forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ChatBoardLeftCell"];

...
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                OrientationEnabledNavigation *navcon = (OrientationEnabledNavigation*)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
                [navcon pushViewController:_chat_board animated:isAnim];
            });
...
}
```

ChatBoardViewController class

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
...
    [time_sections removeAllObjects];

    _messageTotalCount = [[ChatStorage sharedStorage] getMessageCount:chat_id];

    if (self.isLoadAll) {
        self.showingCount = _messageTotalCount;
        [time_sections addObjectsFromArray: [[ChatStorage sharedStorage] getTimeGroups:chat_id count:_messageTotalCount]];
    }else{

        [time_sections addObjectsFromArray: [[ChatStorage sharedStorage] getTimeGroups:chat_id count:self.showingCount]];
    }

    [self reloadData];
...

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
...
NSString *identifier = is_owner ? @"ChatBoardRightCell" : @"ChatBoardLeftCell";

            ChatBoardCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

NSString * parsed_msg = [record objectForKey:@"parsed_message"];
            NSDictionary * decoded = [[ChatStorage sharedStorage] decodeStringToDictionary:parsed_msg];

[cell setText:decoded editMode:_edit_mode];
...
return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *opening chat room*? Do you mean loading the content of some `UITableView`, or navigating to a view controller containing it? If the latter, then the problem is not loading cells. Post some code because if hard to tell the reason based on just a vague description.

Comment: You can also use the time profiler instrument to determine where a delay may be occurring

Comment: Thank you for comments, maybe it's related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431613/how-to-use-lock-unlock

Comment: I updated the post with some codes.