# How to use Lock/Unlock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, sqlite

Here is the code that using SQLite.

This function will be call from some threads.

I don't know well, following code is correct one or not.

There are lock/unlock code.

Please advice me whether I used lock/unlock correctly.

```
- (NSMutableArray*) Query:(NSString *)query_str forColumn:(NSString*)mycolumn
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *query_stmt = [query_str UTF8String];

    [dbLock lock];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
        [dbLock unlock];
        return nil;
    }

    NSMutableArray  *queryResult = [NSMutableArray array];

    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

        NSMutableDictionary * dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

        int num_of_fields = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
        for (int i = 0; i < num_of_fields; i++) {

            NSString * col_name = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_name(statement, i)];

            const char * value = (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
            NSString * col_text;

            if (value)
                col_text = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:value];
            else
                col_text = @"";

            if (col_name && col_text) {
                if ([col_text isEqualToString:@"--"] == NO && [col_text isEqualToString:@""] == NO)
                    [dict setObject:col_text forKey:col_name];
            }
        }
        if (mycolumn == nil) {
            [queryResult addObject:dict];
        } else {
            NSString *tmp = [dict objectForKey:mycolumn];
            if (tmp != nil) {
                [queryResult addObject:tmp];
            }
        }
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    [dbLock unlock];

    return queryResult;
}
```

Comment: `sqlite3_step` might return errors.

Comment: what is the reason?

Comment: Sorry; this is unrelated to locking. I meant that you should check for errors, like you do when preparing. (And consider calling [sqlite3_errmsg()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html).)

Comment: would you please provide me more detail?

Comment: If the return value of `sqlite3_step()` is not `SQLITE_ROW` or `SQLITE_DONE`, you have an error.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am interesting in unlock function's position. because I put unlock at last line of Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The locking is around all the database access functions, so as long as all the other database access code also does similar locking, the database is protected.

The `query_str` access is outside the lock, so it is not protected against concurrent modifications. Whether that could happen in your program is something only you can decide.

Comment: So you mean, query_str should be exist inside the lock?

Comment: That depends. Probably not.